# How to prevent SOME views from being push up by keyboard?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have this video being played in a video view and an EditText view on top of it,
how can I 'lock' my video view onscreen-position but still be able to
push up the EditText when keyboard shows up?

so far adjustResize and adjustPan haven't work, neither using various layout types

Something like this, as you can see, live icon, views counter and video view remain on their original position.

[image]

Comment: You need to post your layout, and a picture of your app so we know what we're dealing with.  You can't specify special behavior for individual views, but if your layout is set up right and sparse enough you can kill the whitespace in a way that makes sense.

Comment: I hope that screenshot clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work for your requirement. Use LinearLayout with androidOrientation as Vertical. and add the VideoView and EditText in the respective order.

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="442dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/test"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: which softInputMode flags arey ou using?

Comment: try removing softInputMode attribute from activity . hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

So, I manage to solve it.

I'm using *android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"*
along with a method to measure the keyboard height (and the rotation) taken from here https://github.com/siebeprojects/samples-keyboardheight

and moving my *EditTextView* with *view.animate().y(value)*

This solutions also fixes the no-margin-between-edittext-and-keyboard issue.

Looks professional and works great.